# How to convert elements type in numpy array from string to int

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array which looks like this

```
arr = np.array([['1','2','3','4','5','6']])
```

For the most common way to convert, loops are required like this.

```
for a in arr:
   for b in a:
      int(b)
```

However, I would like to convert all elements in the array without loops. How could I do that?

Comment: aren't they already strings? (numpy strings)

Comment: The question title says you want to convert to string, but your example shows that you're typecasting to int?

Comment: Ah...my bad. I was confused. It's to convert to integer. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the type of elements at the assignment:

```
arr = numpy.array(['1','2','3','4','5','6'], int)
```

or in case, you want to parse the type of every element in an initialized array, you can use `astype()` method

```
arr.astype('int')
```